# Default case in a switch condition

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
  #include<stdio.h>                                   
  int main()
  {   
      int a=10;
      switch(a)
      {   
      case '1':
          printf("ONE\n");
          break;
      case '2':
          printf("TWO\n");
          break;
      defalut:
          printf("NONE\n");
      }   
      return 0;
  }
```

The program doesn't print anything, not even `NONE`. I figured out that `default` had a typo `defalut`!
I want to know why this syntax error is not detected by the compiler.

Comment: this is a great example why YOU DON'T USE GOTO GUYS YOU ARE SETTING YOURSELF UP FOR FAILURE.

Comment: I agree, that should not have compiled.

Comment: @Hans - OP didn't use GOTO. Unfortunately, it's part of the language and the compiler didn't notice that the label was unused.

Comment: I'm not saying OP used GOTO, I'm just saying any construct where `for:`, `defalut:`, `if:`, `void:`, `do:`, and `this:` are valid is going to make your programming needless hard to debug.

Comment: Did you enable all warnings on your compiler?

Comment: @KerrekSB - cool ! the warning shows up when i compile it with the `-Wall` switch.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`defalut` is just a label in your program that you can jump to with `goto`.  Having an editor that highlights keywords could have made this error easier to spot.

I should also note that your program may have some logic errors.  The character `'1'` is not the same as `1`, and the same with `'2'` and `2`.

Comment: Nice. The statement label probably also suppressed an "unreachable code" warning for the last `printf`.

Answer (score 11):

That's not a syntax error. `defalut` is a valid label, and it could be the target of a `goto`.

Answer (score 8):

tip: if you are using `gcc`, add the option `-pedantic`. it will warn you for unused labels:

```
$ gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic test.c -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:14:10: warning: label ‘defalut’ defined but not used
```