# Random label in C switch statement does not cause error

Tags: c, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default case in a switch condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315330/default-case-in-a-switch-condition)

I can compile this code without encountering any errors. I think there should be an error because of the `assadfsd` in the switch statement.

Why doesn't compilation fail?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int choice =0;
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1 :
            printf("Case 1\n");
            break;                           
        assadfsd :
           printf("Error\n");                                 
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And where do you expect the error? I'd agree with your compiler.

Comment: Now assadfsd : is after one case statement

Comment: If you put warning levels high, `-Wall` or something like that, the compiler should have told you: (1) unused label `assadfsd` and (2) unreachable statement `printf("Error\n")`

Comment: The compiler _might_ warn about unreachable code, but that's perfectly legal.

Answer (score 7):

It is called [label](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/as400clr02.htm)

e.g

```
 start:
     /*statements*/
```

Comment: So i can write any string before : compile won't treat it as error 
becuase it will treat it as label only

Comment: @Anshulgarg - Any string *must* be valid *identifier* and a label name *must* be unique within the function in which it appears.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main(void)
    {
        int choice =0;
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        
        switch(choice)
        {
                      case 1 :
                           printf("Case 1\n");
                           break;
                      assadfsd :
                               int a=2;
                               printf("Error\n");
                      dsefault:
                               printf("Default");
                               
                                             
        }  
        return 0;
        
    }

Comment: Now in this case i defined int a inside label which is against of c as in  c all variables must be declared at function start

Comment: @Anshulgarg said "in c all variables must be declared at function start" No, you can do it on almost everwhere

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the `switch` statement is :

```
switch ( expression ) statement
```

So you can put whatever statements you want instead of "statement". Here you used a label, and it's allowed by the C standard. So your compiler should compile the code without error.

For example, you can use this label using `goto` statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int choice = 1;
    goto assadfsd;

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        printf("Case 1\n");
        break;
    assadfsd:
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is very bad practice and not something that should be used in real applications. It is banned in MISRA-C, for example.

Comment: It depends on the situation. Once I've used statements different from `case` in a `switch` to implement a state machine. But I agree partly, because the example shown in this message is a very bad style.

Comment: Don't tell that to anyone who works on the Linux kernel. The code is littered with label/gotos. It's common practice.

Comment: @Mike The [Linux kernel coding standard](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) is quite crappy, non-scientific and unprofessional in general, so it doesn't surprise me.